# External variable

Tags: shell-script, touchpad

I made simple script to disable my touchpad and bind it to shortcut.

```
enabled=true
  if enabled
    then
      xinput -disable "TouchPad" enabled=false
    else
      xinput -enable "TouchPad" enabled=true
```

How can I make a variable enabled externally or how can I create it in other script and get access to it?

Comment: use `export` command  to export variable

Comment: ok and how to access it then ?

Comment: if you export it, then it should be availabe just as in script. More details you can find i.e. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
device=TouchPad

if
  LC_ALL=C xinput list-props "$device" |
    grep -q 'Device Enabled.*1$'
then
  xinput disable "$device"
else
  xinput enable "$device"
fi
```

That is check whether the device is indeed enabled or disabled rather than maintain a separate *variable* which sooner or later will end up being out of sync with reality and for which you'd need to come up with an exclusive  lock mechanism to prevent concurrent access. That *variable* would have to be tied to the current X server invocation (you may be able to use a property on the root window of the display).

Explanation: `xinput list-props "$device"` lists the properties of the device (in English with `LC_ALL=C`), one of which is the `Device Enabled` one. `grep` looks for lines containing `Device Enabled` and ending in `1` and returns a *true* (0) exit status if found (without outputting anything with `-q`). If found (if the device is enabled) we call `xinput disable`, and `xinput enable` otherwise.

Comment: Nice and could you please explain what each command of this means "LC_ALL=C xinput list-props "$device" |
    grep -q 'Device Enabled.*1$'"

Comment: @ChickenLover, see edit.